# Uncompressing xml feed

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader, compression

My application downloads a zipped xml file from the web and tries to create XML reader:

```
var fullReportUrl = "http://..."; // valid url here
//client below is an instance of HttpClient
var fullReportResponse = client.GetAsync(fullReportUrl).Result;

var zippedXmlStream = fullReportResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

XmlReader xmlReader = null;
using(var gZipStream = new GZipStream(zippedXmlStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) 
{
    try 
    {
        xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(gZipStream, settings);
    } 
    catch (Exception xmlEx) 
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to create XML reader I get an error:

**"The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.**

[image]

When I use the URL in the browser I succesfully download a zip file with a well formatted XML in it. My OS is able to unzip it without any issues. I examined the first two characters of the downloaded file and they appear to be 'PK' which is consistent with a ZIP format.

I might be missing a step in stream transformations. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `GzipStream` for decompressing any http response with `HttpClient`. You can use [HttpClientHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.118).aspx) `AutomaticDecompression` to make `HttpClient` decompress the request automatically for you.

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    // both gzip and deflate
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    var fullReportResponse = client.GetAsync(fullReportUrl).Result;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Web Servers won't `gzip` output all the requests. First they check `accept-encoding` header, if the header is set and it is something like `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip;q=1.0, *;q=0.5` the web server understands the client could support `gzip` or `deflate` so Web Server might ( depends on the app logic or server configuration ) compress the output into `gzip` or `deflate`. In your scenario I don't think you have set `accept-encoding` header so the web response will return uncompressed. Although I recommend you to try the code above.

[Read more about accept-encoding on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply, but setting AutmaticDecompression didn't work. I still get compressed stream of bytes. I added more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353557/download-and-unzip-xml-file